# A function to destructure a alist into a string

Tags: lisp, destructuring

My goal is to take an alist (the alist is the one passed to Drakma's "parameters" param; but this doesn't really matter for this question) and to serialize it into some form of string (in this case, a HTTP parameters string).

So let's take that list:

```
    (list (cons 1 2) (cons 3 4) (cons 5 6))
```

Then what I want, is to endup with a string formatted like this:

```
    "?1=2&3=4&5=6"
```

What I did come up with so far is:

```
    (defvar *s* 
      (make-array 0 
              :element-type 'character 
              :adjustable t 
              :fill-pointer 0))

    ;; (serialize-params) will return a properly formatted string 
    ;; that will be used elsewhere in another function
    (defun serialize-params (params)
      (loop for (a . b) in params
         do (format *s* "~a=~a&" a b))
      (concatenate 'string "?" (trim *s*)))

    ;; Utility function to remove the last character of a string
    (defun trim (str)
      (subseq str 0 (- (length str) 1)))
```

It kind of work, but I really don't like this for a few reasons:

- I don't want to use a special variable
- everytime I run `(serialize-params (...))`, `*s*` just append to the previous call

I think that to solve my issue, I have to use `loop` in some special way and probably that I would have to bind a lexical variable within my function. The problem is that I am not sure how I could append each iteration of `(format nil "...")` to that lexical variable...

Disclaimer: I am really new at lisp.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If your function `serialize-params` calls `PRINT` to do the output, why not print directly instead of building a string using `MAKE-ARRAY`/`FORMAT`/`SUBSEQ`/`CONCATENATE` and printing that with `PRINT`? `FORMAT` can print directly to output.

Comment: Sorry, I think this print in `serialize-params` is just a left over while checking what my code was doing. Let me edit it such that `serialize-params` returns that string instead. The thing here is that I want the output of `serialize-params` to return a string that I am using elsewhere in another function. Thanks for pointing out this confusion.

Comment: I did edit my question. What I really want here is that `(serialize-params)` return a string to be use in another function. Obviously, my function is wrong since it is written into a special variable. However, what I want to know is how to use a lexical variable where I can properly format the string to return with that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with-output-to-string seems to be a good fit for your problem.  It makes a stream you can write to in a loop, and returns whatever you wrote as a string:

```
(with-output-to-string (s)
   (loop with first = t
         for (a . b) in params
         if first 
           do (setq first nil)
              (princ "?" s)
         else
           do (princ "&" s)
         end
         do (format s "~a=~a" a b)))
```

Comment: Wonderful, this is exactly what I was trying to do. The next step is to make sure to understand what is going on here with that `with-output-to-string` macro, and how the `loop` is specifically working. In any case, I changed the body of my function with that macro, and everything seems to be working as expected. This solution is really much cleaner than what I was trying to do :)